# CSS grid spanning columns

Tags: css, grid-layout

In this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Is it possible to span the 5th column with CSS Grid across the grid track?

Answer (score 0):

You can by playing with the `grid-column` CSS property.

Reference here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

In the case you're presenting, we would have to set

```
grid-column: 1 / 3
```

For the element 'Five'

Comment: Probably answering a closed question, but I appreciate the response. Reupvoted.